# Showing all channel groups even without record in database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have *advertiser* and *channel_group* columns. My code is below and the output is there as well. I want my output to contain ALL channel groups ( for instance to A-J, even if there is no value to it) How can i accomplish that? Any tips because i dont have any idea.

```
(SELECT 
    advertiser,
    channel_group,
    ROUND ( sum(cost) ) AS cost
    FROM student_37.data_table

JOIN student_37.dict
    ON student_37.data_table.audiocode = student_37.dict.audiocode
JOIN student_37.channel_group
    ON student_37.data_table.medium = student_37.channel_group.channel
GROUP BY advertiser,channel_group
ORDER BY advertiser)

SELECT 
    advertiser,
    channel_group,
    cost,
    ROUND (cost::decimal/SUM(cost) OVER(PARTITION BY advertiser),2) AS sos_adv ,
    ROUND (cost::decimal/SUM(cost) OVER(PARTITION BY channel_group),2) AS sos_channel_group ,
    ROUND(cost / ( SELECT sum(cost) FROM  sos),2) AS sos    
FROM sos
ORDER BY advertiser,
     array_position(ARRAY['TVP1','TVP2','TVP tem','TVN','TVN tem','Polsat','Polsat tem','unknown'],channel_group);
```

```
"company1";"B";"TV";16537
"company1";"C";"TV";20406
"company1";"D";"TV";33380
"company1";"E";"TV";193633
"company1";"F";"TV";14957
"company1";"G";"TV";5338

"company2";"A";"TV";46580
"company2";"B";"TV";56223
"company2";"G";"TV";80735
"company2";"H";"TV";80874
"company2";"J";"TV";38511
```

I want to get something like this, i dont have any records so i need to some kind of generate them?

```
"company1";"A";"TV";
"company1";"B";"TV";16537
"company1";"C";"TV";20406
"company1";"D";"TV";33380
"company1";"E";"TV";193633
"company1";"F";"TV";14957
"company1";"G";"TV";5338
"company1";"I";"TV";
"company1";"J";"TV";

"company2";"A";"TV";46580
"company2";"B";"TV";56223
"company2";"C";"TV";
"company2";"D";"TV";
"company2";"E";"TV";
"company2";"F";"TV";
"company2";"G";"TV";56223
"company2";"H";"TV";80874
"company2";"I";"TV";
"company2";"J";"TV";38511
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: i have added desired result, but i dont have any connection like company2 C TV 0, just this does not exist in my data, so i do not know how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* channel groups -- even those with no data -- then you want outer joins.

You don't provide sample data, but I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT advertiser, channel_group,
       ROUND( SUM(cost) ) AS cost
FROM student_37.channel_group cg LEFT JOIN
     student_37.data_table dt
     ON dt.medium = cg.channel LEFT JOIN
     student_37.dict d
    ON dt.audiocode = d.audiocode
GROUP BY advertiser, channel_group
```